httplib send content with the content provider and smart pointer
I want to use the c++ httplib feature of the server to send a content with a content provider.
But I want to use it with a smart pointer because of previous calculation doing before the dispatch.
If I simplify the httplib example about it, this is what I am doing:
const size_t DATA_CHUNK_SIZE = 4;

svr.Get("/stream", [&](const Request &req, Response &res) {
  std::size_t data_length = 16; // random length
  auto data = std::make_shared_for_overwrite<char[]>(data_length);

  // doing calculation which potentially fail
  if (!create_data_string(data, data_length)) {
    // return an error
    return;
  }

  res.set_content_provider(
    data_length, // Content length
    "text/plain", // Content type
    [&, data](size_t offset, size_t length, DataSink &sink) {
      sink.write(&data[offset], std::min(length, DATA_CHUNK_SIZE));
      return true; // return 'false' if you want to cancel the process.
    },
    [data](bool success) { /* data will be released after the call */ });
});

The method is working and tested with a real content but I don't know if it is the best to doing this.
What do you think? I need a code review of that code snippet.
Update:
With the response of Red.Wave, I update my send content scenario with a std::string:
const size_t DATA_CHUNK_SIZE = 4;

svr.Get("/stream", [&](const Request &req, Response &res) {
  std::string data;
  data.resize(16); // random length

  // doing calculation which potentially fail
  if (!create_data_string(data)) {
    // return an error
    return;
  }

  res.set_content_provider(
    data.size(), // Content length
    "text/plain", // Content type
    [&, data /* <- copy the data */](size_t offset, size_t length, DataSink &sink) {
      sink.write(&data[offset], std::min(length, DATA_CHUNK_SIZE));
      return true; // return 'false' if you want to cancel the process.
    },
    [](bool success) { /* nothing to do here since data is copied */ });
});

Update 2:
The content provider callback is not deleted or reset after a cancel request. So the data leaves until the next request is called.
Follow the documentation and made a resource releaser callback to free data.

What is your specific question? That one in the comment? Please move it to the text.

You are right, I clarify my demand. If I understand the httplib correctly, the Response is created then destroyed when the url is called. So, I think if I moved the ownership of data from the lambda to the response content_provider_resource_releaser_ member, I win.

smart pointer is an overkill in this senario. std::string will be the most generic data type to use but std::array can also be used with better memory footprint, if the data size is snall and known at compile-time. These changes will result in overal performance boost by removing extra overhead of dynamic allocation and ownership book keeping. Remember: Less is more.

Totally agree! I updated my scenario with a std::string. The data must be copied into the sink lambda, otherwise the data reference becomes a dangling pointer.

" I need a code review" - there's a specific site for that.

Which is? My question was about the code snippet, not my project. I didn't post an issue on cpp-httplib project!

The code is correct and does not exhibit a memory leak. The content provider and the resource releaser closures are alive while Response res is alive, the response object owns the closures, and they all are destroyed when all data is read.
